# Symfony3 : "Attempted to load class "ZipArchive" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement for "PHPExcel_Shared_ZipArchive"?"

Tags: symfony, phpexcel, symfony-3.2, php-ziparchive

I'm using symfony3 and trying to install/use [TwigExcelBundle](https://github.com/MewesK/TwigExcelBundle) on my ubuntu16 server for an excel exporting purpose.
I can install it by when I try to use I get the following error :

> "Attempted to load class "ZipArchive" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement for "PHPExcel_Shared_ZipArchive"?" at /home/web/dgb/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php line 227

I tried to manually install the php7.0-zip extension but it failed :

> apt-get install php7.0-zip
>   ......
>   Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
>    php7.0-zip : Dépend: php7.0-common (= 7.0.30-1~dotdeb+8.1) mais 7.0.18-1~dotdeb+8.1 devra être installé
>                 Dépend: libzip2 (>= 0.11.2) mais il n'est pas installable
>   E: Dépendances non satisfaites. Essayez « apt-get -f install » sans paquet
>   (ou indiquez une solution).

NB : It works fine on my localhost (windows)

Please tell me the solution. What should I do to resolve the problem? Or anyone can suggest me another tool to export excel file using symfony3?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/933076), could be the same situation described.

You only need to purge the packages and install the rigth distribution for your operating system.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Should do what your installation want, run:

```
$ apt-get -f install
```

Or you could try with PHPSpreadsheet :https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Comment: the issue is with the zip ext not with the bundle used, that bundle has a dependency with that extension. so has it the spreadsheet package so it wont work change the package

Comment: I've tried to force the installation but I still get the same error

Comment: have you try uninstall your php and reinstall from scartch??